# I can't mkdir() , and so , i can't upload files

Tags: php, windows

I'm trying to upload an image to a folder with the date of uploading but when i'm trying to execute the code it shows this error :

```
Warning: mkdir(): No such file or directory in 
  C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\code\members\action\addc_do.php on line 63 

Warning: move_uploaded_file(upload/2015-06-21/c49a7b2f6945d903988b17e91d7e6c91.png): 

failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\code\members\action\addc_do.php on line 70 

Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move 'C:\Windows\Temp\phpD6C1.tmp' to 'upload/2015-06-21/c49a7b2f6945d903988b17e91d7e6c91.png' in C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\code\members\action\addc_do.php on line 70 error
```

I think it's about the folder permissions , if yes , how can i add 777 permissions to a folder in windows.

Comment: You are using WINDOWS. Permissions are almost never the issue. And 777 makes no sence in windows

Comment: so why i'm getting this error ?

Comment: What does the mkdir command have as a parameter, I would expect that is wrong

Comment: @ArnonZilca Well OP should not have installed Apache in program files but as Apache is probably running as an admin anyway creating folders should not be a problem

Comment: Also you should really be testing the result of a `mkdir` before attempting to use the folder that it failed to make.

Comment: "The mode is 0777 by default" but "mode is ignored on Windows." [ref](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php)

Comment: Does the "upload" directory already exist?

Comment: No , it doesn't exist . that's why i'm using mkdir

Comment: Thank you guys , i found the error , it was a code-side error , i tried to maked mkdir this way 
` $uploaddir = 'upload/'.date("Y-m-d").'/' ;
mkdir( $uploaddir, 0777);`
while i forgot that i cannot add '/' in mkdir .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[mkdir()](http://php.net/mkdir), by default, creates only one subdirectory per execution. You are are trying to create two at the same time. You can either make two calls like so:

```
mkdir("upload");
mkdir("upload/2015-06-21");
```

or use the recursive option like so:

```
mkdir("upload/2015-06-21", 0777, true);
```